# Primitive Array vs Generic List Comparison

Tags: c#

I have a question on Generic List and Primitive Array (Not ArrayList) what is my question is As array & Generic List are Strong type at compile time so why do we need generics as the array will do same work as Generics.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic array allows you to have a variable length array. For a normal array you have to declare it as `int[3]` for example, saying there are 3 elements in it. A `list<int>` does not have this limitation.

Also, a list has several other methods which can come in handy, for example sorting.

Comment: This is incorrect as you can use Array.Resize.
Generic Lists can delete\insert items anywhere inside the list - this is the advantage

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to do that manually. A generic list will do that for you.

Comment: Perhaps its more cumbersome, but it is possible

Comment: @sternr: When you look at the implementation of List<>, you'll see that is uses an array internally. Of course you can do everything with a simple array and rewrite the Lists code, but why should you?

Answer (score 3):

Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

One important point is that arrays are mutable by design, and that is not always desired.